# Validate existing user-id using ng-change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So i'm trying to create a **user-id validation** using `ng-change` the problem is that i think my `if/else statement` is wrong. Because sometimes its giving me the wrong value for my `ng-class` to work its working when typing but once the input is deleted its giving me the wrong value.

**html**

```
<div ng-class="{'has-success': vm.value == 'true', 'has-danger': vm.value == 'false'}">
     <input type="text" name="userId" class="form-control form-control-sm" ng-class="{'form-control-success': vm.value == 'true', 'form-control-danger': vm.value == 'false'}"
                placeholder="Username" ng-model="userData.userId" ng-change="vm.checkId(userData.userId)" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/" ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="14" required>
     <div ng-messages="regForm.userId.$error" class="colorValid" role="alert">
        <div ng-message="minlength">Your field is too short</div>
        <div ng-message="maxlength">Your field is too long</div>
       <div ng-message="pattern">Invalid Characters</div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

**controller**

```
function checkId(data) {
    if (data) {
      return dataservice.getUser(data).then(function (data) { // get request
        if (data) {
          console.log('User-ID not available');
          vm.value = 'false';
        }else {
          vm.value = 'true';
          console.log(data);
          console.log('User-ID Available');
        }
      });
    } else {
      vm.value = 'null';
    }
}
```

Thanks any suggestion is welcomed.

Comment: are you sure you are always getting correct value of id from `ng-change`.

Comment: @lakshay theres no problem getting the value from the `UI` my problem is i cant correctly manipulate the `vm.value` for my `ng-class`

Comment: can you please ellaborate what you want from your `if-else` statement

Comment: I just want it to say like there's already an existing user and your user id is available

Comment: according to your code  if  `dataService.getUser()` request returns data then your user does not exist....right or is it vice-versa?

Comment: @lakshay the other way around if the service returns a data with values the user-id already exist if not it will return an empty string and will output the **user-id** is available

Comment: it's like allowing the user to select a username on a website if data comes username already exists and u can't use it  if not username is available ...is that right?

Comment: @lakshay exactly.

Comment: in that way your code looks fine where is the error coming?

Comment: the line if (data) { .. } will always trigger, as the data is present even if it's returned as empty string. Please try the code in my answer

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you use same variable name for checkId argument and data returned from your API call, so it's hard to understand what are your intentions.. Also please clarify what does getUser() returns in 'data'.

Try following modification of your code, added the check for empty string as well, as after user deletes the value, it's still set but it's empty.

```
function checkId(userData) {
  if (userData && userData!="") {
    return dataservice.getUser(userData).then(function (data) {
      if (data!="") {
        console.log('User-ID not available');
        vm.value = 'false';
      } else {
        vm.value = 'true';
        console.log(data);
        console.log('User-ID Available');
      }
    });
  } else {
    vm.value = 'null';
  }
}
```

Comment: the `dataservice.getUser` check if there's an already existing `user-id`

Comment: i understand that, but what values is it returning?  What are you trying to achieve with this line  "  else if (data === null) "  ?  Pls see my edit and try the code, check if userData is empty string, that should set your vm.value correctly

Comment: sorry forgot to delete that `else if (data === null)` i already edited my post if the getUser has a match it will fetch a bunch of string values if not it will return an empty string.

Comment: See my edited code - u need to check also the data returned from the call for empty string. Pls try the code

Answer (score 1):

```
function checkId(userID) {
    if (userID != null) {
        return dataservice.getUser(userID).then(function(user) {
            if (user) {
                vm.value = false;
                console.log('User-ID not available');
            }else {
                vm.value = true;
                console.log('User-ID Available');
            }
        });
    } else {
      vm.value = false;
    }
}
```

and change your html as:

```
<div ng-class="{ 'has-success': vm.value, 'has-danger': !vm.value }">
    <input type="text" name="userId" class="form-control form-control-sm" ng-class="{'form-control-success': vm.value, 'form-control-danger': !vm.value}" placeholder="Username" ng-model="userData.userId" ng-change="vm.checkId(userData.userId)" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/" ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="14" required>
     <div ng-messages="regForm.userId.$error" class="colorValid" role="alert">
        <div ng-message="minlength">Your field is too short</div>
        <div ng-message="maxlength">Your field is too long</div>
        <div ng-message="pattern">Invalid Characters</div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Your answer in default will already set the `vm.value` to **true**. And i already solved my problem by using `ng-model-options="{debounce: 750}"` it seems like a `$timeout` thanks anyway.